# What is the VB equivalent of @model dynamic in C# Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a `View` (vbhtml) in ASP.NET MVC 5 which uses a dynamic model, I know it's easy in C# to do this by writing

```
@model dynamic
```

**But how can I specify this in vbhtml?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of C# Dynamic in vb.net instead you can replace `dynamic` into `Object` and make sure you set `option strict off`.
The `dynamic` keyword brings `Option Strict Off` equivalent functionality to C#.

Comment: the problem is with late binding not option strict

Answer (score 1):

The key difference based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537660.aspx) is:

> If a late-bound call is made to an object that implements the
>   IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface, Visual Basic binds to the
>   dynamic object by using that interface. If a late-bound call is made
>   to an object that does not implement the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
>   interface, or if the call to the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface
>   fails, Visual Basic binds to the object by using the late-binding
>   capabilities of the Visual Basic runtime.

And since you mentioned:

> The problem is with late binding not option strict

You reference a `dynamic` object by using late binding. In C#, you specify the type of a late-bound object as `dynamic`. In Visual Basic, you specify the type of a late-bound object as `Object`. For more information, see [dynamic (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) and [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx).

You can create custom `dynamic` objects by using the classes in the [`System.Dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.aspx) namespace. For example, you can create an [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) and specify the members of that object at run time. You can also create your own type that inherits the [`DynamicObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) class. You can then override the members of the `DynamicObject` class to provide run-time dynamic functionality.

An example could be found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

**Update**:
VB binder does not work with things typed as `dynamic` in medium trust. Try setting your app to full trust. Also The `Option Strict On` disallows late binding In VB.Net. If you are trying to use strongly typed helpers like `Html.EditorFor` while your view is not strongly typed to a class, So you need to indicate the model type in the `@Page` definition:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="VB" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of YourApplication.YourModelClass)" %>
```

Then you can safely use those helper methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what I'm trying to do is using such statement in my View (vbhtml) file: `@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Id)` where `Id` is bound in runtime! If I use `ExpandoObject` it will cause a design-time error telling `Id` is not a member of `ExpandoObject`, this occurs for `DynamicObject` also. All I want to do is to create my View dynamically base on my model, which the model itself is dynamic and created by the information retrieved from database. it seem's I should search for another way mohandes ;)

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab why you are trying to use strongly typed helpers like `Html.EditorFor` while your view is not strongly typed to a class? Please see my *Update*.

Comment: uhhh, replying to your question is pretty much difficult! but in a short words, because my MVC application is not a standalone app, and in real usage it gets ride on another application as a OWIN middle-ware which the models are strongly-typed there!

Answer (score 1):

VB equivalent of `@model` dynamic in C# Razor is `@ModelType`